# What do these functions do?

Tags: c

I found the following two functions from a code written by other person but I don't really understand what these functions do.

```
typedef  union
{
    t_float f; //float
    unsigned int ui;
}t_bigorsmall32;

static inline int PD_BADFLOAT(t_float f)  /* malformed float */
{
    t_bigorsmall32 pun;
    pun.f = f;
    pun.ui &= 0x7f800000;
    return((pun.ui == 0) | (pun.ui == 0x7f800000));
}

static inline int PD_BIGORSMALL(t_float f)  /* exponent outside (-64,64) */
{
    t_bigorsmall32 pun;
    pun.f = f;
    return((pun.ui & 0x20000000) == ((pun.ui >> 1) & 0x20000000));
}
```

I would appreciate if anyone can explain what they do.
And I would also like to know if there's any built-in alternative functions from standard library or C++.

Comment: Please, read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253896/2988 to understand why "explain this code to me" questions are off-topic, and what you can do to improve your question so that it becomes more narrow and focused and is no longer too broad.

Comment: @Robidu No, I don't believe CR wants you to post questions regarding code written by others. Also this is not a complete program but a snippet.

Comment: @Lundin: O.k., point taken...

Comment: **I seriously don't understand why there are 5 downvotes to this question, because there is not much to be understood about it except that it does some very bad bit twiddling, unless the person happens to be a bitnerd who knows IEEE 754 binary representations by heart - and most programmers *shouldn't***

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Downvotes can indicate lack of research. Since this quest reads 'I found the following functions and don't understand what they do', it qualifies for quite some of those.

Comment: @Mast How should I ask this question then? and what should I have researched? I didn't even know what to google to find what I wanted to know.

Comment: @ZackLee Maybe include a bit more context like where you found the code etc. Also, you could explain the parts you understood and the parts you don't. PS: I did not downvote

Comment: Aside from the title, I don't see what is so wrong with this question. The current accepted answer also dignifies it, and epitomises why it's so hard to research this particular point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is easy to see, the code reinterprets the bytes [IEEE 754 binary32 float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) as a 32-bit unsigned integer via union type punning. It then uses the bit-wise operations to check particular bits in the exponent of the floating point number. Understanding what it *actually does* requires intricate knowledge of the binary32 storage format.

---

`PD_BADFLOAT` checks if [the biased exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_bias) is either 0 or the maximum value 255 as [0 and 255 have special meanings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding) (those with exponent 0 are [subnormal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) and zero; and 255 meaning NaNs and infinities). Notice however, that these are not *bad floating point numbers* - but they do not behave like regular numbers either.

---

The second checks if the unbiased exponent is outside the range [-63, 65] (the description seems to be wrong w.r.t. the bounds) meaning that its magnitude is above than 2⁶⁵ (~ 3.7 * 10¹⁹) or below than 2⁻⁶³, (~ 1.08 * 10⁻¹⁹).

All this is very implementation-specific and non-portable - it seems that these have been programmed with speed in mind.

---

The former is an exact equivalent of the negation of the standard macro [`isnormal`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.3.5).

For the latter, the portable way I believe is to use the C99+ function [`frexpf`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.6.4) to get the exponent from the `float` and then compare against the desired limits, or by just constructing constants that represent these values and comparing the absolute value with these limits.

Hence something like

```
static inline int PD_BADFLOAT(float f) {
    return !isnormal(f);
}

static inline int PD_BIGORSMALL(float f) {
    int exp;
    if (isnormal(f)) {
        frexpf(f, &exp);
        return exp < -63 || exp > 65;
    }

    // return 1 for subnormal numbers and
    // NaN, INF...
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation!

Comment: @ZackLee I ran some tests and even my exponents were off.